# Let $B$ and $C$ be sets. Suppose $|B| = m$ and $|C| = n$. Find the following cardinality:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $B$ and $C$ be sets. Suppose $|B| = m$ and $|C| = n$. Find the cardinality:

$|\mathcal{P}(B \times \mathcal{P}(C))|$

I want to check if the following is correct:

The cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(C)$ will just be $2^n$ since each set has $2^n$ subsets. $B$ has cardinality $m$, so $|B \times \mathcal{P}(C)| = m\cdot 2^n$. Taking $|\mathcal{P}(m\cdot 2^n)|$ gives us a cardinality of 
$\begin{align} 2^{(m \cdot 2^n)} \end{align}$

Comment: Yes you are correct.